# Dont show result in form

Tags: android, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have this code in HTML5 using jquery. Fails when trying to run it on Android, don't show the result. Please helpme.

I try to use jquery mobile.

When I run it on my PC runs fine.

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery-1.9.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery-mobile-1.2.0/jquery.mobile.min.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#calcular").click(function(Event){
                    var v1 = $("#v1").val();
                    var v2 = $("#v2").val();
                    var resultado = parseInt(v1) + parseInt(v2);
                    $("#r").val(function(){
                       return resultado; 
                    });
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form name="formsuma" id="suma">
            <table align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Valor 1: </label></td>
                    <td><input name="valor1" id="v1" type="number" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Valor 2: </label></td>
                    <td><input name="valor2" id="v2" type="number" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Resultado: </label></td>
                    <td><output form="formsuma" name="resultado" id="r"></output></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" id="calcular" value="Calcular" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </form>
```

Comment: Q1. Is it working in browser? Q2. Is the `js` folder located beside html file.? Q3. Are you calling the html file correctly?

Comment: R1. Its working in browser, test in Chrome, and work fine. R2. The folder its fine. R3. I guess so.